# Openldap granting write access for groups

Tags: openldap

I want to give an admin group write access

```
cn=admin_group,ou=group,dc=kml,dc=de
dn: cn=admin_group,ou=group,dc=kml,dc=de
cn: admin_group
description: All users
member: uid=uf,ou=people,dc=kml,dc=de
objectclass: groupOfNames
```

the acl :

```
olcAccess: {0}to  * by  group.exact="cn=admin_group,dc=kml,dc=de" write by users read by * auth
```

if i authenitcate as uf It did not work, i tried all examples in found in the web, but i got allways

```
0x32 (LDAP_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS)
```

Comment: Where is this ACL applied? {-1}frontend, {0}config, {1}mdb? Are you sure you're bound as a member of that group to the server? I.e. `ldapwhoami` returns as expected?

Comment: This acl is in (1)mdb

Comment: ldapwhoami -x -D "uid=uf,ou=people,dc=kml,dc=de" -W
Enter LDAP Password:
dn:uid=uf,ou=people,dc=kml,dc=de